# How to extract the content between the <sup>2</sup> tag and put that content in a seperate array

Tags: javascript

I have a array which contains string. I want to extract the content wrapped between `<sup style="color:red;">1</sup>` tag and put the content in a seperate array from the string.

I have tried the following method, but dont know where I am wrong. It always giving me empty array.

```js
let sampleArray=[
  "<p>If you no longer <sup style=\"color:red;\">1</sup>wish to receive <sup style=\"color:red;\" >2</sup>emails from this sender , pleas?ick here and confirm your request .</p>"
]

let unique= [];
    let myArray = [];
    sampleArray.map(object => {
      if (object.includes("<sup>")) {
        var Result = object.includes("<sup>")
          ? Object.values(object.match(/<sup>(.*?)<\/sup>/g))
          : Object.values(object.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g));
        var Fresult = Result.map(word =>
          word.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "").replace(/[[\]]/g, "")
        );
        Fresult.forEach(item => {
          if (item.includes(","))
            item.split(",").forEach(item1 => {
              myArray.push(item1);
            });
          else myArray.push(item);
        });
      }
    });
    unique = myArray.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
    console.log(unique)
```

The expected result is

```js
[
  "1",
  "2"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct but there were some minor issues like you have provided `<sup>` in most of your conditions, it should have been `<sup` which I have corrected below:

```js
let sampleArray = [
  '<p>If you no longer <sup style="color:red;">1</sup>wish to receive <sup style="color:red;" >2</sup>emails from this sender , pleas?ick here and confirm your request .</p>',
];

let unique = [];
let myArray = [];
sampleArray.map((object) => {
  if (object.includes("<sup")) {
    var Result = object.includes("<sup") ?
      Object.values(object.match(/<sup(.*?)<\/sup>/g)) :
      Object.values(object.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g));
    var Fresult = Result.map((word) =>
      word.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "").replace(/[[\]]/g, "")
    );
    Fresult.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.includes(","))
        item.split(",").forEach((item1) => {
          myArray.push(item1);
        });
      else myArray.push(item);
    });
  }
});
unique = myArray.filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are always looking for digits you could use this regex to get your desired result:

```js
const regex = /\<sup style=\\"color:red;\\" ?\>(\d)\<\/sup\>/gm;
const str = `<p>If you no longer <sup style=\\"color:red;\\">1</sup>wish to receive <sup style=\\"color:red;\\" >2</sup>emails from this sender , pleas?ick here and confirm your request .</p>`;
let m;
let results = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    results.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(results);
```

if it can be digit or string then this will do the trick:

```js
const regex = /\<sup style=\\"color:red;\\" ?\>(.*?)\<\/sup\>/gm;
const str = `<p>If you no longer <sup style=\\"color:red;\\">1</sup>wish to receive <sup style=\\"color:red;\\" >2</sup>emails from this sender , pleas?ick here and confirm your request .</p>
<p>If you no longer <sup style=\\"color:red;\\">hello</sup>wish to receive <sup style=\\"color:red;\\" >world</sup>emails from this sender , pleas?ick here and confirm your request .</p>`;
let m;
let results = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    results.push(m[1])
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regex will help you.

```
let sampleArray=[
  "<p>If you no longer <sup style=\"color:red;\">1</sup>wish to receive <sup style=\"color:red;\" >2</sup>emails from this sender , pleas?ick here and confirm your request .</p>"
];
let regexp = /[^>]*[\d][^<]*/g;
let firstElement = sampleArray[0];
firstElement.match(regexp);
```